# Converting char* string to lowercase using tolower() causes SIGSEGV - what's wrong?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

I've found the following code in a legacy project that seems to cause some trouble:

```
for( ; *str; ++str )
    *str = tolower(*str);
```

The trouble is, we get an SIGSEGV at the moment the result of tolower() should be written back to *str . This is what I got from using printf() debugging and the stracktrace produces, as we're using JNI here and thus attaching a debugger to the C libraries is not working for us.

The code fails if it's compiled with gcc on linux. Running the same thing on windows (CMake is being used for this cross-plattform setup) works fine.

Where can I look to find the reason for this? Any hints appreciated :)

thank you - Markus

Comment: What is `str` pointing to? Not the string constant?

Comment: It's passed into my function: myfunction(char* str)

Comment: 'my function' => You have no control over caller?

Comment: What Michael wanted to say is, modifying string constants can lead to segmentation faults. Here is why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string

Comment: Yes, that's what I (and later @ouah in the anwer) wanted to say ;-)

Comment: Hm, not really :( But maybe I got it now: the caller might be passing a pointer into myfunction that - for some reason - cannot be written to. Can I check this? 
I'll try to trace down where the given string comes from. Thanks a lot for your fast replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals are non-modifiable:

```
char blop[] = "modifiable string";
char *bla = "non-modifiable string";

*blop = tolower(*blop); // OK
*bla = tolower(*bla);   // not OK, modifying a string literal
```

Comment: +1, but `tolower()` function doesn't expect `char*` and doesn't modify anything ;-) What you meant is what the OP refers to as `myfunction()` in comments above.